# Using map and other high order functions

Tags: list, dictionary, scheme, racket

I am still learning about high order functions and going to be quizzed on it soon.  I am trying to write a program that takes 2 lists of the same length and subtracts the first from second, item by item, until you get 0 in the first position.

```
(check-expect (min (list 1 1 1) (list 2 4 6)) (list 2 4))
(check-expect (min (list 1 1) (list 2 3)) (list 1))
```

I can easily do this without map, but Is there any way I can use `map` here?

```
(map - 1 (list ...))
```

or when I pass it on to the first of a list, or rest.

wont work. I know it takes in a function and passes on to each element of a list.  I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good example to start learning about `map`. The `map` higher-order procedure takes a list as input, and returns another list *of the same length* as output, where a function was applied to each of the elements in the input. See why this is not such a clear-cut case for using `map`? the output lists are smaller than the inputs!

Of course, it *can* be done, but it's not that elegant, and obscures the true purpose of `map`:

```
(define (min lst1 lst2)
  (if (zero? (first lst2)) ; if the first position in lst2 is zero
      (rest lst2)          ; then return the rest of it.
      (min lst1            ; otherwise advance recursion
           (map - lst2 lst1)))) ; ok, here `map` was useful
```

To understand what's happening in the last line, imagine that the input lists are one on top of the other:

```
'(2 4 6)
'(1 1 1)
```

Then, `map` applies the `-` function element-wise:

```
(- 2 1)
(- 4 1)
(- 6 1)
```

And the result of each operation is collected in a new list:

```
'(1 3 5)
```

This is a special case of `map`: when there's more than one list after the function, it applies the function to the first element of each list before advancing to the next - hence the function must accept as many arguments as there are lists. The usual case with `map` is that you simply apply the function to each of the elements in a single list, and but the way this is a good place to use `lambda`:

```
(map (lambda (x) (* x x))
     '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(1 4 9 16 25)
```

Comment: I see. So map takes in one list, not two. And what do cdr and car do?

Comment: @Josh `map` can take one _or more_ lists, but it's more common to pass only one. And haven't you heard about `car` and `cdr` yet? ok, let's change them to something more familiar: `first` and `rest`.

Comment: Thanks! I've learned more from reading your comments than I have from my own profesor and I passed my other exam largely thanks to you.You actually make this fun to learn.

Comment: @Josh Wow, thank you! it really _is_ my pleasure to teach people how to program :)